# SQLite3 can't DELETE row, no such column Error

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete, new-operator, delete-row

I have a simple sqlite database setup with a table called sightings and a column within that table called name. I can run normal SELECT queries and INSERT's and UPDATE's just fine, but when I try to run DELETE, it prepends "new." into the column that I gave it and then says it doesn't exist:

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM sightings WHERE name = "blah";
Error: no such column: new.name
sqlite> DELETE FROM sightings WHERE names = "blah";
Error: no such column: names
```

The column is called "name" and when I select that column, it adds "new." in front of it, but when I select a wrong column that doesn't exist ("names" like above), it just says it doesn't exist normally, without the "new.".
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on deletions on that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a DELETE TRIGGER and that TRIGGER wrongly uses **new.name** to reference the name column of the deleted row (for a DELETE TRIGGER old. is used to reference columns from the deleted row).

You should change the TRIGGER to use **old.name** instead of **new.name**.

- **new.column** is only applicable for INSERT or UPDATE triggers.
- **old.column** is only applicable for DELETE or UPDATE triggers.

As per :-

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of
>   the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the
>   form "NEW.column-name" and "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the
>   name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.
>   OLD and NEW references may only be used in triggers on events for
>   which they are relevant, as follows:
>
> - INSERT  NEW references are valid
> - UPDATE  NEW and OLD references are
>     valid
> - DELETE   OLD references are valid

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Perhaps consider the following example :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sightings (name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deleted_sightings (name TEXT); /* Table to be populated by the trigger */
INSERT INTO sightings VALUES ('blah'),('notblah'),('anothernotblah');
/* Normal deletion without triggers */
DELETE FROM sightings WHERE name = 'blah';
SELECT * FROM sightings; /* RESULT 1 (sightings table after deletion)*/

/* Add the row that was deleted again */
INSERT INTO sightings VALUES('blah');

/* Add a valid AFTER DELETE TRIGGER referring to the old column */
/* The Trigger will add a row to the deleted_sightings table using the value from the deleted row */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS correct_trigger 
    AFTER DELETE ON sightings 
    BEGIN INSERT INTO deleted_sightings 
        VALUES(old.name); 
    END;
DELETE FROM sightings WHERE name = 'blah';
SELECT * FROM sightings; /* RESULT 2 (sightings table after deletion)*/
SELECT * FROM deleted_sightings; /* RESULT 3  deleted_sightings table */

/* Add a Trigger that will try to add a row to the deleted_sightings table */
/* BUT will result in the new.name column not being found as there is no */
/* new. for a DELETE trigger only old. */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS incorrect_trigger AFTER DELETE ON sightings BEGIN INSERT INTO deleted_sightings VALUES(new.name); END;
/* Show the triggers */
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'trigger'; /* RESULT 4 - The triggers as per sqlite_master */
DELETE FROM sightings WHERE name = 'blah'; /* <<<<< DELETE will fail due to incorrect trigger */
```

The results being :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the error due to the incorrect trigger :-

> ```
> /* RESULT 4 - The triggers as per sqlite_master */
> DELETE FROM sightings WHERE name = 'blah'
> > no such column: new.name
> > Time: 0s
> ```